# Recognizing text that is rotated in an image

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, tesseract, easyocr

I detected the text in my image using EASYOCR and used TESSERACT to do the recognition, but the text that is rotated could not be detected. How I can detect rotated text?
I used this code:

```
# # Text detection with easyocr and recognition with tesseract
import cv2
import easyocr
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('image 18.jpg')

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Initialize the EasyOCR text detector
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])

# Detect text in image
results = reader.readtext(gray)

# Image preprocessing for Tesseract
_, processed_image = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Recover text regions detected by EasyOCR
for (bbox, _, _) in results:
    # Extract coordinates from bounding box
    x_min, y_min = map(int, bbox[0])
    x_max, y_max = map(int, bbox[2])
    # Vérifier les limites de l'image
    x_min = max(0, x_min)
    y_min = max(0, y_min)
    x_max = min(image.shape[1], x_max)
    y_max = min(image.shape[0], y_max)
    # # Extract text region
    if x_max>x_min and y_max>y_min :
        text_region = processed_image[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]

        # Text recognition with Tesseract
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(text_region, lang='eng')

        # # Draw the bounding box on the image
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Display text detected by Tesseract
        cv2.putText(image, text, (x_min, y_min - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 2)


# Display image with bounding boxes and detected text
cv2.imwrite('Text Detection_2.jpg', image)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Do you know the angle at which the text is rotated? You could try rotating the image in the opposite direction and process it multiple times at all the required angles.

Comment: no, I don't know the angle of rotation, since there can be several angles of rotation in each text.
  Rotation angle can change from text to text